# Hour Choice - a choice in a short time?

Tags: phrase-meaning

If someone in a discussion said "You can either support A or B. Hour choice", what does "hour choice" mean then? A choice that can be immediately made?

I searched online and found this:

Hour Choice | Rivoli Introduced in February 1999, the Hour Choice concept was conceptualized by Rivoli Group to cater to the fashion and value conscious customer, keeping in mind the trend-setting generation. It has evolved as the ultimate shopping haven for affordable fashion timepieces and jewelry.

The "hour choice" seems to mean that "if you are not affordable for normal luxury (enjoying luxury for months or years, as the rich do), you can choose a short time (for example, an hour) to taste it (you have no money to enjoy the luxury for a year - each day you spend one thousand dollars for the luxury for a year; you can spend one hundred dollars for enjoying one hour of luxury (24 hour a day, one day of enjoying the luxury would cost you $2,400 which you do not afford.).

That's how I understand "hour choice" for the time being. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Where did you hear/read this expression? The only references I can find to it are related to the brand name you quoted in the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is obviously a typo of “your choice”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that it was actually supposed to be "your choice", not "hour choice".